# Ler e editar uma palavra específica numa string (c#)

Tags: c#

Eu tenho um arquivo de texto:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pI0mJ.jpg

Eu coloquei esse pedaço de código numa string, e preciso substituir o nome dentro de  (no caso Mateus) pra um outro nome de outra string.

Comment: já tentou fazer algo? a ideia do SO não é bem "fazer o código" e sim ajudar a encontrar soluções/problemas..  https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode utilizar o String.Replace.

Ex:

```
 public static void Main()
   {
      String s = new String('a', 3);
      Console.WriteLine("The initial string: '{0}'", s);
      s = s.Replace('a', 'b').Replace('b', 'c').Replace('c', 'd');
      Console.WriteLine("The final string: '{0}'", s);
   }
```

Referência:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/czx8s9ts(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

O que eu entendi da sua pergunta foi: 
Você quer mudar o que está dentro das tags `<name>..esse texto aqui..</name>`
sendo que este texto pertence a uma `String`

Então faça o seguinte:

```
 // adicione a referência
    using System.Xml;

    //carregando o texto que você mencionou em uma string
    String textoXml = "<Farmer><name>nome</name><isEmoting>false</isEmoting><isCharging>false</isCharging></Farmer>";

   // Criando um novo xmlDocument
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.InnerXml = textoXml;// pasando para o Xml o conteúdo da string

    //Pegando o elemento pelo nome da TAG
    XmlNodeList xNodeList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("name");

    foreach (XmlNode xNode in xNodeList)
    {
       xNode["name"].InnerText = "outroNome";// alterando o texto desejado
    }

    String textoAlterado = xmlDoc.InnerXml; //texto alterado
```

O resultado será:

```
<Farmer><name>outroNome</name><isEmoting>false</isEmoting><isCharging>false</isCharging></Farmer>
```